# Original tweet or retweeted?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using Tweepy with python and trying to get the original tweets authored by set of users (i.e., I want to exclude any tweet in their timeline that is actually a retweet). How can I do this with Tweepy?
I tried something like this and I do not know if it works:

```
tweets = api.user_timeline(id=user['id'], count=30)
for tweet in tweets:
    if not tweet.retweeted:
        analyze_tweet(tweet)
```

Does the `api.user_timeline()` return only original tweets? Or retweets of this user as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tweepy by default doesn't include retweets in user_timeline therefore tweet.retweeted will always be false. To include retweets you can specify include_rts as True like

```
tweets= api.user_timeline(id=user['id'], count=30,include_rts=True)
for tweet in tweets:
        if not tweet.retweeted:
              analyze_tweet(tweet)
        else:
              #do something with retweet
```